# Passing MainActivity as a parameter RecyclerView Adapter in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am following this android tutorial

https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/blob/student/Lesson03-Green-Recycler-View/T03.07-Solution-RecyclerViewClickHandling/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerview/MainActivity.java

In order to handle item clicks in the RecyclerView.Adapter which is the instance GreenAdapter in the tutorial, we create an interface to receive onclick messages from the activity. We then implement the interface in the MainActivity by overriding onListItemClick. The code is shown below

```
public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {
public interface ListItemClickListener {
    void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex);
}  
final private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
public GreenAdapter(int numberOfItems, ListItemClickListener listener) {
    mNumberItems = numberOfItems;
    mOnClickListener = listener;
    viewHolderCount = 0;
}}
```

and the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GreenAdapter.ListItemClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
mAdapter = new GreenAdapter(NUM_LIST_ITEMS, this);}
```

The **this** is referring to the activity instance, but the GreenAdapter constructor takes a ListItemClickListener type.

How is this possible. How can an Activity be passed/cast as ListItemClickListener type.

Answer (score 0):

Here `this` means that your `MainActivity` has the implementation of the `ListItemClickListener`. Read the documentation of the Android from the official documentation.

Comment: Since you implemented GreenAdapter.ListItemClickListener, the MainActivity is an instance of GreenAdapter. Hence when you pass this into the RecyclerView Adapter, you're essentially passing the instance of the ClickListener.